# Display pdf on a web page using pdf stream returned from web service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, web-services, pdf, jsreport

How can I display pdf on a new tab in angularjs when a pdf is being returned as a stream.

pdf stream header captured by fiddler is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Vary: Origin
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="report.pdf"
File-Extension: pdf
Number-Of-Pages: 1
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Content-Length: 18126
```

AngularJS code

```
externalService.getReport(template).then(function (data, error) {
            if (data) {
                type = 'application/pdf';
                var newTab = $window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
                newTab.document.write("<object width='400' height='400' data='" + data + "' type='" + type + "' ></object>");
            }
        }), function (error) {
            if (error) {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There ya go: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/; just pass in the URL.

Comment: I have a stream coming from web service. It is not a url to pdf file.

Comment: How did you get that stream?

Comment: Also, if you bothered to read the API, it also works with a pre-populated `Uint8Array` with the file contents.